# Software updater waiting for "q" key press

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

A few days ago Ubuntu's Software updater awaits user input (q to Quit). I have attached a screenshot with the problem. I think this is related with **fake sync from Debian**.

What does this mean and how to fix this ?

[image: Software updater]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, presumably inadvertently, installed the [apt-listchanges](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apt-listchanges) package. This packages lets you review the list of changes whenever you upgrade packages. The software that's running in the terminal and that waits for you to press `q` is the [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), by the way.

Remove the `apt-listchanges` package and this will go away.

This is completely unrelated to “fake sync from Debian”, that just happens to be how the maintainer of `p7zip` described the latest update to the package.

Comment: Removed `apt-listchanges`, waiting for an update to test if this worked.